# if (isset($_GET)) parameter not working as expected PHP

Tags: php

I have this url

```
http://localhost/example/products.php/full/grains?name_product=rice&refer_url=index-desktop-sidemenu
```

ON LIVE SERVER SOMETHING LIKE

```
http:www.example.com/products.php/full/grains?name_product=rice&refer_url=index-desktop-sidemenu
```

I am trying to check if $_GET["name_product"] is present with if, but it seems not to detect `name_product` in the URL when its present.

This is what I tried.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET["name_product"])){ 
    echo $new_tag = $_GET["name_product"];
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
?>
```

IT always echo not found even when name_product is in the URL as written above.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["name_product"])){  
    echo $new_tag = $_GET["name_product"];
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
?>
```

Still echo not found even when name_product is in the URL as written above.

EDITED: This is my mod rewrite rule

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^products$ ./products.php
RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ ./products.php?linkcheck=$1&name_product=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^404$ ./404.php
RewriteRule ^500$ ./500.php

IndexIgnore *
```

ADDED products.php to the main file

Comment: Simple test, add an `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,1) . '</pre>'`

Comment: Do you have some kind of `mod_rewrite` rule in `.htaccess`? That could mess with the GET params.

Comment: @petrhejda Yes I do

Comment: @Shasha Ok, please update the question with the `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: @Petrhejda Would update the rule

Comment: @PetrHejda Done the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`full/grains?name_product=rice` where you are using `grains?` so do you have any .htaccess file, if it exist then you can use like

```
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /grains.php?name_product=$1&refer_url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Let me know if it works but this will change the present structure of the url...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after .htaccess I only get full/grains

Comment: @Shasha what are you trying to say can you please be much descriptive...

Comment: Hi, done the update, added my mod rewrite and also products.php is the page, while grains is a rewritten get parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ ./products.php?name_product=$1&refer_url=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

products.php
if (!empty($_GET["name_product"])){ 
echo $new_tag = $_GET["name_product"];
echo "Found";
} else {
echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz Sorry about that, done it already.

Comment: Thank You @Shasha